# how to make chrome or firefox more sensible about html mistakes

Tags: html, google-chrome-extension, cross-browser, firefox-addon

i use Chrome and Firefox to test my webpages. but there is a problem. They are less sensitive about html mistakes and some time after uploading a page the mistakes start to show themselves. and then i see for example i have a  tag that when i decided to replace it with a  tag i forgot to change the close tag. in local and solely it wasn't problem but in server among some others it start to become a big problem.....
is there any plugin or add-on or a setting to control their sensitiveness?

thanks all about validatores, but what about validating when there is php embedded. i test them while php is embedded and there where so poor result ...

Comment: You can give it a strict doctype i think im not sure. But best way is to just use an html validator.

Comment: Here's a link to a validator: http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 1):

Yo,

Browsers are very tolerant towards html that doesn't follow the w3c standards. Often the code will work if it's close enough however if it is very wrong your browser won't be able to understand it. If you want your code checked then you should use a html validator, however with more experience you should be able to spot code mistakes like an hawk spots a mouse in a field.

Here's a validator I found on google! http://www.freeformatter.com/html-validator.html

Best of Luck!